# Rename files without copying in same folder

Tags: vbscript

I have files with following naming convention.

RE12356_GJ123456789.DAT

I need to rename the file to RE12356_GJ123456790.DAT without copying the files using VBS i.e. I need to increment by 1, everytime when I run VBS file. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FileSystemObject has a method .GetFile(FileSpec) that returns an object for the file FileSpec. Those objects have a (writable) .Name property. So get the .Name, modify it, and write/assign the new one.

To give you some ideas (looping over the files in a folder, finding the file(s) to change, extracting the number to increment):

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

WScript.Quit demoMain()

Function demoMain()
  demoMain = 0 ' assume success

  Dim sDDir    : sDDir        = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".\")
  Dim reVictim : Set reVictim = New RegExp
  reVictim.IgnoreCase = True
  reVictim.Pattern    = "^(victim)(\d+)(\.txt)$"
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In goFS.GetFolder(sDDir).Files
      If reVictim.Test(oFile.Name) Then
         WScript.Echo "found:  ", oFile.Name
         oFile.Name = reVictim.Replace(oFile.Name, GetRef("FINC"))
         WScript.Echo "renamed:", oFile.Name
      End If
  Next
End Function ' demoMain

Function FINC(sM, sG1, sG2, sG3, nP, sS)
  FINC = sG1 & Right(100 + sG2 + 1, 2) & sG3
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript finc.vbs
found:   victim00.txt
renamed: victim01.txt

cscript finc.vbs
found:   victim01.txt
renamed: victim02.txt

cscript finc.vbs
found:   victim02.txt
renamed: victim03.txt
```

How to copy with overflow of the counter is left as exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the "move" command which will not actually rewrite the file but will just move the entry in the file table... which is essentially a "rename"

If you don't want to use filesystemobject.move  you could issue a command line rename command via: Wsript.shell

like...

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "cmd /c rename somefile.txt newname.txt"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

or as Ekkehard.Horner pointed out:

```
  Dim fso, f, s
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFile(filespec)
   f.name = "newFileName.txt"
```

see: [Name Property (FileSystemObject)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zawxett8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: Ekkehard points out first... how to actually do exactly what you want.