# Move file with name causes error 5, invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

**It seems I have some problems with the hard drive itself. It's acting strange. Some files appear duplicates and I delete the duplicates. A few minutes later i refresh the directory and they are back. Refresh again and they are gone. Files are visible on one computer but not the other. I will try to trouble shoot it and see where what the issue is. Thanks for all the help so far it may be more than one problem acting together.**

I have used this code to rename and move files from one location to another on my network drive.

The video files are named 00001, 00002 etc.. and since the counter resets i need to rename the files to something that can work on a harddrive.

So all files are renamed to `<date> <time>.MTS`

This code used to work but now it just stoped working by some reason.

```
Sub MoveFiles()
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 2 'first line of files
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(r, "A")) Or IsEmpty(Cells(r, "B"))
        dirPath = Cells(r, "C") + "\" + Cells(r, "B")
        If objFSO.FileExists(dirPath) Then
            ' file exist output error message
            MsgBox ("Filen finns redan!!! " + Cells(r, "A") + "   " + Cells(r, "B"))
        Else
            FromName = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + Cells(r, "A")
            ToName = Cells(r, "C") + "\" + Cells(r, "B")

            ' none of the methods below work.
            Name FromName As ToName
            Name ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + Cells(r, "A") As Cells(r, "C") + "\" + Cells(r, "B")
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop



End Sub
```

[image]

Since the code does not create the error message that the ToName exsists then it's not a "duplicate" issue.
If I run the following code

```
If objFSO.FileExists(ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + Cells(r, "A")) Then
    MsgBox "test"
End If
```

I get the message box, which means that FromName file exsists.

So in short the file exsists and the filename that it will become does not exsist. Also the paths (directories) exsist as they are created in a earlier sub(). And I have double checked it. So what can be the problem?
I'm completly lost here.

Edit; Workbook picture added:
[image]

Comment: try checking the destination folders `Cells(r, "C")`

Comment: Does the issue persist when pointed to a non-network drive?

Comment: @paulbica It's there. The directory exsist.

Comment: @CodyG. Will try that later, thanks for the tip

Comment: It seems I have some problems with the hard drive itself. It's acting strange. Some files appear duplicates and I delete the duplicates. A few minutes later i refresh the directory and they are back. Refresh again and they are gone. Files are visible on one computer but not the other. I will try to trouble shoot it and see where what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (not tested — YMMV):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveFiles()
    Dim rownum As Long
    rownum = 2 'first line of files
    Dim objFSO As Object        ' Required because of Option Explicit
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim FromName as String
    Dim ToName as String

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rownum, "A")) Or IsEmpty(Cells(rownum, "B")) or rownum > 1048576
        ToName = CStr(Cells(rownum, "C")) + "\" + CStr(Cells(rownum, "B"))
        If objFSO.FileExists(ToName) Then
            ' file exist output error message
            MsgBox ("Filen finns redan!!! " + Cells(rownum, "A") + "   " + Cells(rownum, "B"))
        Else
            FromName = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + CStr(Cells(rownum, "A"))

            ' none of the methods below work.
            '' Name FromName As ToName
            '' Name ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + Cells(rownum, "A") As Cells(rownum, "C") + "\" + Cells(rownum, "B")

            objFSO.MoveFile FromName, ToName

        End If
        rownum = rownum + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

A few things changed:

- `Option Explicit`: always use it at the top of every VBA file.
- Never use `Integer` — use `Long` instead.
- With `Option Explicit`, you have to have `Dim` statements for every variable.  This prevents you from accidentally creating a new variable because of a typo in a variable's name.
- in the `Do` loop, include a sanity check on `rownum` so you don't try to access a nonexistent row.
- Only assign `ToName` once, and save its value.
- Use [`FileSystemObject.MoveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6(v=vs.84).aspx) to rename.
- Use `CStr()` to make sure the value you get from `Cells()` is a `String`.  That will reduce the risk of unpleasant surprises due to unexpected input data.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17660117/2877364) is not an exact duplicate, but may also have some helpful information.

Comment: I have not yet had time to test the code yet, but just some comments on the stuff you noted. Rownumber will never ever go above 250 so integer is fine. The count is the number of files on the memory card of my video camera. Sure I could do one second videos and get a high count but it's unlikely. I know of Option Explicit but I choose to not use it. I hate the warning messages when I'm in the middle of coding and just want to try something. The `ToName` is only set once, only difference is that you set it before you know if the file already exist. No difference really. Other stuff, good points

Comment: will try it out. Just very odd that it stoped working all of the sudden.

Comment: @Andreas Using `Cells()` directly (without `CStr()` or the like) can cause unexpected failures if the Excel format of one of your cells changed.  I don't know if that's the case here, but I've certainly seen it bite people before.

Comment: It seems I have some problems with the hard drive itself. It's acting strange. Some files appear duplicates and I delete the duplicates. A few minutes later i refresh the directory and they are back. Refresh again and they are gone. Files are visible on one computer but not the other. I will try to trouble shoot it and see where what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks! And thank you for your help. I will mark this as accepted as the issue is (probably) not code, but hardware/network. And your efforts should not go unnoticed.

Comment: @Andreas I greatly appreciate it!  @ me if you do have any further code issues once you get your hardware sorted out.