# Is it possible to rename the downloaded attachment from alm?

Tags: vbscript, hp-alm

I'm downloading an attachment from hp alm and saving on my system. Can i rename this file after saving through alm workflow script?

For eg: I'm downloading a report.doc from alm into my system. Post download i want to rename the file to abc.doc from workflow code. Is it possible to achieve this and how?

Kindly provide your valuable inputs on this. Thanks.